# How do I cluster/group people together given their durations for an given event?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

I am new to machine learning and do have a very large dataset for a set of 100 people over a period of 1 year.  and the goal is to find out who are buddys based on their lunch times.

I have the following dataset:

```
Person  StartTime EndTime Duration(dif for start and end times)
Person1 Time11    Time12   diff1
Person2 Time21    Time22   diff2
Person3 Time31    Time22   diff3
Person4 Time41    Time32   diff4
```

Now I would like to cluster/group people together based on their times ( with +/- 5 minutes time difference, meaning if start time and end time of person 1 is 12:00 - 1:00 PM and person 2 is 11:55 - 1:05 they fall under the same group relative to Person 1)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In any particular language? What format is your data in?

Comment: Hi benten, does language matter? its just a person't name and start time (with date) and end time (with date), thank you!

Comment: I mean are you programming in a particular language? or are you indifferent.

Comment: indifferent as long as i understand the process.

Answer (score 0):

Derive a graph based on this. The weight of an edge is the overlap in lunch times. Maybe normalize by the lunch duration, number of people having lunch at the same time, and maybe also add a nonlinear weighting such as log(1+duration).

On the resulting graph, run a *community detection* algorithm.